# Have value in a script variable how to pass it in asp controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
        function getgeoip(json) {

            var a = json.ip;

           document.write(a);
           
            document.write("Geolocation information for IP address : ", json.ip);
            document.write("Country : ", json.country);
            document.write("Latitude : ", json.latitude);
            document.write("Longitude : ", json.longitude);
          
        }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=getgeoip"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="lblip" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:Label ID="lblcountry" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:Label ID="lbllatitude" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:Label ID="lbllongitude" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

Please help me how can I get the value in variable a into any of the asp labels.
In short help me to assign a asp control with a scripting variable

Comment: var value="somevaue";   document.getElementById("lableid").innerHTML=value;

Comment: do you want to set value of a lable via javascript ? is that you mean ??

Answer (score 0):

It is little bit unclear what you are asking, i guess you need to assign value of variable **a** to your label.

then you can use

```
document.getElementById("lblip").innerHTML=a;
```

something like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4cq7qxL1/)**

IF you what a jquery solution then try below

```
 $('#lblip').html(a);
```

Comment: does this solution works only for html controls or should it work for asp controls also

Comment: yes it will work for asp controls too, you still have any problems ?

Comment: yea this code is perfect but in my case its not working thanks for the help

Comment: Ok can you tell me what is the value of variable a ?? in your case fix a debugger and find it's value

Comment: @SabuThomas first try something like  document.getElementById("lblip").innerHTML="testing"; this  , if it is working then problem resides in your variable, let me know this is working or not

Comment: value of a is my ip address

Comment: please show me a small code of passing a value from java script variable to a asp label on fiddle

Comment: @SabuThomas did you try my above method ?? is it works ?

Comment: @SabuThomas i don't know if there any asp.net fiddle is available , i think it is not

Comment: I am using json in script to fetch ip in this case its not working

Comment: @SabuThomas  where did you call getgeoip method ? what is its argument i mean json ?? from where did you pass that argument ? what is it's value ? can you update more code ?

Comment: @SabuThomas put your json data here

Comment: all the code I have given In this I have used a json plugin and I m amble to get my ip address in var a I checked it with alert its working

Comment: why did you use script type="application/javascript "  ??

Comment: use  <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: ok if your ip is alerting then it should be work where did you write our code ? did you write it inside the function ?

Comment: some browsers doesnot suppoert application/javascript

Comment: did you getting any error when running ? i mean some error  like undefined or object expected something like that ???

Comment: I reoved application and i place text/javascript its working same as earlier...No errors like that

Comment: Do you know any method to get the text in alert to the database then my its done

Comment: @SabuThomas are you sure you get a value inside that function ? or the function is calling when page load ?? did you try with plain text instead of  variable a ???

Comment: @SabuThomas are you mean get  data from database and alert it ? or display it in your page ??

Comment: yes i tried with plain text its loading with no errors

Comment: No I meant that I am able to alert the Ip from java script can I directly pass it to my database without passing it to any other control any how at the end i need it in my database

Comment: @SabuThomas yes it is possible , use ajax and pass your ip as ajax data then in your server side you got the value from there you can update it to database

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can assign use this code :

```
document.getElementById('<%= lbllongitude.ClientID%>').value = a;
```

The ClientID property is globally unique among all controls defined in an ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery code

```
$('#<%=lbllongitude.ClientID%>').html(yourData);
```

get the element based on its ID that's why we use the selector `'#'`.
The control we want to get is an asp tag not a pure html tag.
so to get the real Id generated on DOM use `<%=lbllongitude.ClientID%>`

Finally we use the `.html()` (`.innerHtml()` in javascript) function because the `<asp:Label>` is the equivalent of a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried to use json script to get the Ip of the viewers and I was able to show it in alert but was no able to capture it ina label or textbox.I fetched the ip of the viwers in an alternative manner now not with json. Went for sever side code and it did my pupose.

```
 ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];


            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(ipAddress);
            }
```

In this way I saved the Ip of the viewers in my database and it is successfully working.
Thank you all for helping with answers